# E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-base

Tags: ros, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, I am trying to install ROS-indigo on a machine running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. as I follow all of the instructions presented on the website I get this error:
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-desktop-base
same error is received when I try to install the full package. Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221913/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-desktop-base/) by [wafi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25242/wafi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you successfully go over these commands?;

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116

sudo apt-get update
```

If yes, what is your environment?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1